# gson JsonDeserializer is causing NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, deserialization, gson, noclassdeffounderror

I'm not sure what else there is to say.  I've tried removing and adding classes, but that doesn't seem to help.  I have not experienced this problem before so I don't really know what to do.

Other gson objects work fine.  It's just the Deserializer.

Comment: I've tried to guess the answer (below), but it would be **much** easier to help you if you post your code

Comment: I'm sorry, next time I will post code. I'm not sure if it would've been useful in this case; the problem had nothing to do with logic, the problem was with the java class loader

Answer (score 0):

[JsonDeserializer](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html) is to be found at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer and the [Gson](http://gson.googlecode.com) jar should be on your classpath.

Comment: All of that was there.  I fixed the problem by dragging the all of the libraries I needed into my libs folder, and then adding them again as Android libraries.